# what is the normal wait time these days for iPad apps

Tags: iphone, ipad

What is the normal wait time these days for iPad apps to move from "Waiting for Review" to "In Review".

Once "In Review" How long before they accepted or rejected?

This is my first app submission so wondering.

Submitted on 6th Sep.
Still "Waiting for Review"

Comment: There can be no definitive answer to this question, because this changes every week.  Also, this isn't really a programming question, but one about Apple's acceptance process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not directly related to your question but since this is your first submission it will go towards what to expect:  Apple has officially released their app submission guidelines today, If you read through them it might save you some headache if you have broken any of their rules.

Comment: wasn't app submission guidelines available earlier also?

Comment: No, its always been a big mystery.  There was a lot of speculation as to what Apple looks for in submissions but there were no actual clear 'rules' published before.

Comment: do u know where i can find the document u r referring to?

Answer (score 2):

After submitting a number of apps, as well as updates, i can say the total turn around time from submitting to available in app store ranges generally from 5-9 days. After they go "In Review" it is generally within the next business day or so to go to accepted or rejected. Hope this helps.

Note: this isn't an official report, just some gathered knowledge from going through the process a number of times.